# I am beginning to worry or I begin to worry

Tags: present-continuous

I **begin** to worry because I have not received the parcel you sent me 2 weeks ago.

If I want to emphasize the anxiety that is growing each day, can I use I **am beginning** to worry ?

Comment: I was going to cite [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+begin+to+think%2CI+am+beginning+to+think&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=26&smoothing=3) to show that the progressive / continuous verb form is gradually becoming more common with ***beginning** [to do something]*. But whereas that's true across the past couple of centuries, [the trend seems to have reversed in recent decades.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+begin+to+think%2CI+am+beginning+to+think&year_start=1989&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3). Your choice, but I'd use the continuous.

Answer (score 1):

**I am beginning to worry** is correct and natural, and it implies increasing anxiety, so the best choice for this context.

**I begin to worry** is bad grammar in this context because present simple implies a repeated event or a continuous state, but "begin" is not happening repeatedly, and is never a continuous state (something cannot continually begin).

Answer (score 0):

> I'm (getting) worried/It worries me (that) the parcel you sent me (2 weeks ago) hasn't arrived yet.

To stress the constant growth of your anxiety, you could use either "increasingly worried" or "more and more worried".

Answer (score -1):

**I am beginning to worry** would be for present tense, and the past tense would be **I began to worry**

Comment: And which one of those is the one the author should use? This doesn’t answer the question, it just makes some statements about some of the words in the question.